# Fallo al poner IP estatica en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, redes, ubuntu-server

Hola na todos tengo un problema al poner la IP estática en ubuntu 20.04. El problema viene que yo tenia el Ubuntu 16.04 con la IP estatica configurada en el archivo /etc/Network/Interfaces y me funcionaba bien. Pero al actualizar primero a la versión 18 de Ubuntu que cambiaron sino estoy equivocado en la versión 17 los archivos de configuración a yaml.
Bueno pués desde que actualice de  la 16 a la 18 el Ubuntu al iniciarse se tira 5 minutos buscando la red. He configurado el archivo  /etc/netplan/01.netcfg.yaml asi:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd #si utilizamos NetworkManager lo cambiamos por este
ethernets:
eth0: #nombre de nuestra tarjeta
dhcp4: no
dhcp6: no
addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
gateway4: 192.168.1.1
nameservers:
addresses: [192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
```

Luego el el archivo de Interfaces comente todo lo que tenia.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
#allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#address 192.168.1.2
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#network 192.168.1.0
#broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

#gateway 192.168.1.1
#dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Lo raro que si que tengo red, se conecta tanto por wifi como  por cable, pero si hago ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 20:1a:06:b1:5b:38  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 18  

    eth0:avahi: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 169.254.5.190  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
    ether 20:1a:06:b1:5b:38  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    device interrupt 18
```

Como se ve no tengo la IP estática. ¿Hay que modificar algún archivo más? He mirado por internet y la configuración parece correcta.

Comment: La verdad es que es un poco lio como lo tienen montado ahora con el NetworkManager ese, no es que me guste demasiado... Yo simplemente, dado que tengo entorno gráfico (y diria que tu tambien por la otra pregunta que acabamos de gestionar), me limito a ponerla via gnome mediante el diálogo de los parametros del sistema.  Alli encontrarás "Red" y podras establecerla mediante diálogos sin problema espero.

Comment: Hola masterguru, ayer no te pude responder me tuve que ir. Ya lo he solucionado, en el archivo Interfaces y resolv.conf comente lo comente todo. No deje nada sin comentar. Ahora arranca bien y se conecta a la primera. Lo único que si cuando arranca el Ubuntu si aprietas Control + Alt + Enter sale como se carga el sistema, y ahí si sale que  Failed mount Interfaces. Pero como comento ya no da problemas. Este problema según he leído es más común de lo que parece, ya que si tienes configurado el archivo Interfaces manualmente en Ubuntu 16 o inferior y actualizabas a 17 o posterior se da.

Comment: Vale, me alegro pues :-)  gracias por la info.  Por cierto, veo en tu perfil que no has marcado nunca ninguna respuesta como aceptada, y ya llevas muchas preguntas. Léete [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y [este otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) del porque es importante hacerlo, cuando las respuestas son válidas para tu pregunta.

Comment: Ok no sabía gracias